# How to create dummy interface in /etc/systemd/network?

Tags: networking, debian, systemd, systemd-networkd

I am trying to create an equivalent to the following for systemd.

```
auto strongswan0
iface strongswan0 inet static
  address 10.0.2.1/24
  pre-up ip link add strongswan0 type dummy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
cat << "EOF" >> /etc/systemd/network/10-strongswan0.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=strongswan0
Kind=dummy
EOF
cat << "EOF" >> /etc/systemd/network/20-strongswan0.network
[Match]
Name=strongswan0

[Network]
Address=10.0.2.1/24
EOF
```